# How does Phonegap to migrate platform app

Tags: phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

I have an app that maps routes developed for Android.
Now I want to make the app for iOS, I'm estuando about PhoneGap and I have some questions:

1 - The Phone Gap convert my java code to Objective C?

2 - This is the solution most widely adopted platform for migrating apps?

3 - The api google directions works with Phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

from their home page:
Easily create apps using the web technologies you know and love: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.

Phonegap doesn't convert your code, you can write code in html, javascript and css and phonegap will wrap it as an app for all platforms.

Regarding google directions, I never worked with it, but as far as I know there is a javascript api so you should be able to use it with phonegap.